# How do I save Fbo to use as a Texture for a canvas?

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing an application that has XY plot. I have a routine that records hundreds of points (using the `Points` instruction) dozens of times per second. Periodically, I'd like to draw the points into a texture using a Kivy Fbo, so my canvas isn't processing megabytes of vertex instructions. Once the points are drawn, I'd like to load the texture back onto my canvas. The canvas is also processing other graphics instructions, so I can't just clear it or anything like that.

I'll put a code snippet of what I'm trying to do below, although I'm sure there's something wrong with my approach. Currently, the call to `save()` on the Fbo texture throws this exception:

> AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'encode'

Kivy version: 1.10.1, Python 3.5.4 (64 bit Windows 7):

```
def _save_persist(self):
    #imports:
    #from PIL import Image
    #from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
    #from kivy.uix.image import Image as kiImage
    #from io import BytesIO

    self.persist_fbo = Fbo(size=(self.width,self.height))        

    #chan_info is a list containing data about each channel
    #_persist_chan_inst is a dictionary of InstructionGroup objects
    for chan in self.chan_info:
        persist_inst = self._persist_chan_inst.get(chan.chan_name)
        if not persist_inst is None:
            self.persist_fbo.add(persist_inst)

    self.persist_fbo.draw()       

    bytebuff = BytesIO()

    pimg = Image.new("RGBA",(int(self.width),int(self.height)),(0,0,0,0))
    pimg.save(bytebuff,format="PNG")
    bytebuff.seek(0)       
    self.persist_fbo.texture.save(bytebuff) 

    img = CoreImage(arg=bytebuff,ext='PNG') 
    self.texture = img
```

Comment: The problem is that the `save` method is trying to treat your argument (`bytebuff`) as a file name string and calling `bytebuff.encode('utf-8')`. I suspect that save method can only be used to save the texture to a file. You may have to use the `pixels` attribute of the texture to create an `Image`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I would use any way that works, but I can't figure out a way to "flatten" the graphics instructions to a texture. I tried drawing on a PIL image and using that, but the blending looked atrocious and the ImageDraw class is not very performant.